# unresolved import 'discord.ext.tasks'

Tags: python, visual-studio, discord.py, visual-studio-2019

let me start of by saying i know little to nothing about visual studio.

here's what i've done so far: 
i've updated pip `-m pip install --upgrade pip`

```
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.6 MB 819 kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-21.2.3
```

and tried to update discord.py `pip install --upgrade discord.py`

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: discord.py in c:\users\bruh\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0 in c:\users\bruh\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from discord.py) (3.7.4.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\users\bruh\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in c:\users\bruh\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.10.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\bruh\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (21.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\bruh\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\users\bruh\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\bruh\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\bruh\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.2)
```

but it still says `unresolved import 'discord.ext.tasks'`

Comment: try to put before you import it
os.system("pip install discord.py")
because your maybe not using the same interpreter as you've installed to

Comment: are you using vscode or visual studio?

Comment: when i use `os.system("pip install discord.py")` it prints out the same thing `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable` i'm using visual studio 2019 at the moment

Comment: from what is at the top of vs its saying the python version it's on click on that and go to add no environment then go to the existing environment and at the environment put the path to the python.exe that is in c:\users\bruh\appdata\roaming\python\python37\

Comment: it does not appear to be a **python.exe** in python37, if i had to guess i have to reinstall python?? i'm gonna do that right now and see if that fixes my problem

Comment: maybe in the folder before it?

Comment: well i didn't find a it anywhere so i uninstalled 3.7 and got 3.9, but it still tells me `unresolved import 'discord.ext.tasks'`, when i type `pip install --upgrade discord.py` in the terminal i get `Requirment already satisfied` for all of them, been searching for a while but got nothing

Comment: maybe try this py -3.9 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]

Comment: well it did something but it still says unresolved, i'm sorry that i took too much from your time, i think i'm just gonna look for another program to use

Comment: its fine use from my experience the bet IDEs are:  pycharm  and vscode